# Can somebody explain what "Bandwidth" means in AWS Data Transfer (Billing)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, data-transfer, billing

I have been trying to see how data transfer costs have scaled for the last year. I am confused as to what these line items shown below mean - Which one is transfer out to internet? What is Download Bandwidth consumed? What is the difference between them? [Bandwidth in Bill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNt5J.png)

I have tried matching Download bandwidth consumed to Region-Out to Internet from CE to no avail.

Comment: I would suggest you create a support case with AWS customer services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two type of transfer techniques here.

1. Data transfer
2. Bandwidth

Under data transfer, all the transfers you do within aws comes here,
And, all the transfers you do from aws to public (outside aws) is considered in Bandwidth.

Both above transfers are measured in GB per month.